# Collection view auto layout

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, autolayout, xcode6

I'm making a project to show several images on a iPad, my problem is that I can't make the UICollectionView adjust to the size of the screen, and also when It rotates to landscape the auto layout does not work, I'm really lost with this, any help is very welcome.

Here is a simple example I made on Git: [Git project link](https://github.com/brunojasgv/CollectionViewWithAutoLayout)

Here is some code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var mainMenuCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    var images = ["220.jpg","220.jpg","220.jpg","220.jpg","220.jpg","220.jpg","220.jpg","220.jpg","220.jpg","220.jpg","220.jpg","220.jpg","220.jpg","220.jpg","220.jpg","220.jpg","220.jpg","220.jpg","220.jpg","220.jpg","220.jpg","220.jpg","220.jpg","220.jpg","220.jpg","220.jpg","220.jpg","220.jpg","220.jpg","220.jpg","220.jpg","220.jpg","220.jpg","220.jpg","220.jpg","220.jpg","220.jpg","220.jpg","220.jpg"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView!, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return images.count
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView!, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UICollectionViewCell!
    {
        var cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as HomeCollectionViewCell
        cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named:images[indexPath.row])
        cell.textLabel.text = "Woof Woof"
        return cell
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you sample project you didn't set up any auto layout constraints. For example the collection view should have 4 constraints: one for each direction:
[image: constraints]

If you set all the 4 constraints to 0 it will always have the same size as it's container.

For more information you should read the apple developers guide: https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html

Or start with some tutorials:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1

Comment: Bloody Hell I couldn't setup the constrains... I was using xcode6 beta 6...Now I updated to xcode 6.1 and everything works fine, thanks for the help :)